# How to resize and display images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, image

I am attempting to read images from a list of paths (10 items long) returned via an ajax function, resize each one and then display one after the other on the page. However, the below code only displays the first image (resized) and none of the others. I am fairly sure the resizing works as the printed sizes look correct. Below is my code in JavaScript:

```
// Helper function
function scaleSize(maxW, maxH, currW, currH){
    var ratio = currH / currW;
    if(currW >= maxW && ratio <= 1) {
        currW = maxW;
        currH = currW * ratio;
    } else if(currH >= maxH) {
        currH = maxH;
        currW = currH / ratio;
    }
    return [currW, currH];
}

function get_similar_images(image_name) {
    console.log(image_name)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/get_similar",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({name: image_name}),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            image_list = data['images']
            category = data['category']
            for (var i=0; i<image_list.length; i++) {
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = "static/products/"+category+"/"+image_list[i];
                var actualH;
                var actualW;
                var newH;
                var newW;
                img.onload = function(){
                    actualW = this.width;
                    actualH = this.height;
                    console.log(actualW, actualH)
                    var newSize = scaleSize(300, 300, actualW, actualH);
                    console.log(newSize)
                    img.width = newSize[0];
                    img.height = newSize[1];
                    document.getElementById('imageDiv').appendChild(img)
                };
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! First, is your `image_list.length` greater than 1 ?

Comment: Yes- it is 10 items long

Comment: And when you log the `newSize`, you have the expected values (width and height less than or equal to 300) ?

Comment: Yes here is an example of the output for the first two items (old size and then the new size): 227 900
 [75.66666666666666, 300]
 380 583
 [195.54030874785593, 300]

Comment: First you should do a `return [Math.round(currW), Math.round(currH)];` in your `scaleSize` function to avoid strange floating numbers, even if it won't resolve your problem.

Comment: You said that that the image resizing is working, correct?  So your problem is that you're only loading one image and not all of them?  If that's the case, can you post what your http response looks like -- just the 'data' var from `success: function(data) {`

Comment: @hightempo, here is the data from the console:  Object {category: "dresses", images: Array[10]}
category : "dresses"
images : Array[10]
0 : "image4069.jpg"
1 : "image4086.jpg"
2 : "image4041.jpg"
3 : "image4054.jpg"
4 : "image4017.jpg"
5 : "image4067.jpg"
6 : "image4010.jpg"
7 : "image4030.jpg"
8 : "image4063.jpg"
9 : "image4052.jpg"
length : 10

Comment: @Melanie I gave you a full answer that should help you understand why it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we simplify your `for` loop like that :

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = image_list[0];
img.onload = function() {
  console.log(img);
};

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = image_list[1];
img.onload = function() {
  console.log(img);
};
```

You will understand where your mistake comes from. `onload` is an event, which means it's running asynchronously from your your code. You're updating `img` value with a new image element (and a new `href` attribute) before the first `load` event is triggered. Thus the `onload` event is actually called after the last update of the `img` variable, which actually happen when your reach the last loop of your `for`.

**Why ?**

Because a `for` loop doesn't create a new scope for the variable `img`, so each time you touch the `img` var, even if you're putting `var` in front, the original `img` is updated.

You should then use a function, because a function actually create a new scope for variables that are declared (`var myVar`) inside it :

```
function injectAndResize(imageUrl) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = imageUrl;
  var actualH;
  var actualW;
  var newH;
  var newW;
  img.onload = function() {
    actualW = this.width;
    actualH = this.height;
    var newSize = scaleSize(300, 300, actualW, actualH);
    this.width = newSize[0];
    this.height = newSize[1];
    document.getElementById('imageDiv').appendChild(img);
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < image_list.length; i++) {
  injectAndResize(image_list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code.
1) Image width and height are CSS properties and may be `undefined` in your `img.onload` handler. Use `this.naturalWidth` instead.
2) `img.src = 'url';` triggers image load. Place it **after** `img.onload`.

```
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        image_list = data.images;
        category = data.category;
        for (var i=0; i<image_list.length; i++) {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.onload = function(){
                var actualW = this.naturalWidth;
                var actualH = this.naturalHeight;
                console.log(actualW, actualH)
                var newSize = scaleSize(300, 300, actualW, actualH);
                console.log(newSize)
                this.width = newSize[0];
                this.height = newSize[1];
                //also think what to do with images which are already there
                //probably remove
                document.getElementById('imageDiv').appendChild(this)
            };//img.onload
            img.src = "static/products/"+category+"/"+image_list[i];
        }//for
    },//success
```